# /usr/lib/libodbc.so missing in 12.04

Tags: installation, upgrade, apt, libraries

Before upgrading to ubuntu 12.04, I had the library `libodbc.so` in `/usr/lib`.
I am pretty certain it was part of the `unixodbc` package.

Somehow it has gone missing after my last upgrade to 12.04 (64 bit), and some proprietary software depends on it.

Which package do I have to install to get it back?

Answer (score 8):

You need install [unixodbc-dev [image: Install unixodbc-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unixodbc-dev) and [libmyodbc [image: Install libmyodbc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libmyodbc) packages, to do the same open terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev libmyodbc
```

Comment: To install `libmyodbc` in ubuntu xenial (16.04), check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/800216/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-install-odbc)

Answer (score 2):

This has been killing me for a couple of days too. The location that works for me now is:

```
/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Also note that my freetds config had also mysteriously stopped working. I had to

`cp /etc/freetds/freetds.conf /usr/local/etc/`

Comment: I actually found it back under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so`. I am not a big fan of all this moving around of libraries.

Comment: @mirk that is why `cp` is not the correct method. This should be done with a symlink (`ln -s`)

Comment: I don't think `ln -s`is ideal in directories maintained by the distribution. My prefered method is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

For those on 32 bit:

```
sudo apt-get install tdsodbc
```

look under

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```